# How to deal with async operations in react functional components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, promise, react-functional-component

Consider the following component:

```js
function MyComponent() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState<any|null>(null);

  function loadData() {
    if (loading) return;

    setLoading(true);

    fetch(/* ... */)
      .then(setData)
      .catch(console.error)
      .then(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data === null) return;
    console.log(data);
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <button onClick={loadData} disabled={loading} />
  );
}
```

1. Is it safe to use `function`s with references to hook variables within react functional components (e.g. `loadData`)?
2. Is it safe to call `setX(...)` in `loadData` after the async operation completes?
3. Is this a safe design when dealing with async code inside functional components in general? If not, what pattern *should* be used when dealing with promises inside functional components?

Comment: Is something not working? Not really sure what you're trying to ask, or what you mean by "safe".

Comment: So far, this is working. However, I remember having issues with similar patterns when I was just starting out, leading me to avoid `function` inside functional components at all. As an example of "safe": using the value of `data` after the async call would be "unsafe" since the component may have changed since the value was originally loaded. This makes me wonder if it is similarly "unsafe" to use `setData`?

Comment: So the question is basically: is this a bad design and if so, what is a good design when dealing with promises?

Comment: It's a good design if it's doing what you want it to do. You should try to ask questions about the problems you have, rather than try to speculate about what *could* go wrong.

Comment: The question is: does it do what I want it to do or are there unforeseen side-effects? E.g. risk of accessing data after the component is unloaded; risk of state not being updated as expected; risk of code running when it's not supposed to - basically anything causing error log prints from react? This is a simple example but consider a complex component with multiple `useState`, `useCallback` etc.

Comment: @ChrisHamilton I disagree - as software developers, it's our job to think about all possibilities and make sure nothing *does* go wrong. In this case my problem is that I have a gap in my understanding, hence I ask for more information.

Comment: Sure, but you need to be more specific about what you don't understand. From my perspective, I don't know why you would think any of those things are a risk. I don't even know what you're trying to accomplish, besides setting these two state variables.

Comment: "From my perspective, I don't know why you would think any of those things are a risk.". Ok - that to me indicates that yes, indeed - the code seems safe to you. Using the `function` keyword in functional components does not bring any risks (1), `setX` functions will still work, even after an async call (2) and on the whole, you do not see any issues with the design (3). Is this correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249570/discussion-between-felix-zy-and-chris-hamilton).

Comment: I feel like you want to understand which approach is the best practice. 
So far you are doing good.  To answer your questions briefly,  I'd say, they are all total valid react/js syntax. You will face a problem once you get an error :) .